# Java Generic List<List<? extends Number>>

Tags: java, generics

How come in java we cannot do:

```
List<List<? extends Number>> aList = new ArrayList<List<Number>>();
```

Even though this is OK:

```
List<? extends Number> aList = new ArrayList<Number>();
```

Compiler error message is:

> `Type mismatch: cannot convert from ArrayList<List<Number>> to List<List<? extends Number>>`

Answer (score 74):

In Java, if `Car` is a derived class of `Vehicle`, then we can treat all `Cars` as `Vehicles`; a `Car` is a `Vehicle`. **However, a `List` of `Cars` is not also a `List` of `Vehicles`. We say that `List<Car>` is *not covariant* with `List<Vehicle>`.**

Java requires you to explicitly tell it when you would like to use covariance and contravariance with wildcards, represented by the `?` token. Take a look at where your problem happens:

```
List<List<? extends Number>> l = new ArrayList<List<Number>>();
//        ----------------                          ------
// 
// "? extends Number" matched by "Number". Success!
```

The inner `List<? extends Number>` works because `Number` does indeed extend `Number`, so it matches "`? extends Number`". So far, so good. What's next?

```
List<List<? extends Number>> l = new ArrayList<List<Number>>();
//   ----------------------                    ------------
// 
// "List<? extends Number>" not matched by "List<Number>". These are
//   different types and covariance is not specified with a wildcard.
//   Failure.
```

However, the combined inner type parameter `List<? extends Number>` is not matched by `List<Number>`; the types must be *exactly identical*. Another wildcard will tell Java that this combined type should also be covariant:

```
List<? extends List<? extends Number>> l = new ArrayList<List<Number>>();
```

Comment: Seems like List<List<? extends Number>> on the LHS would better match the poster's intent.

Comment: @erickson But `List<List<? extends Number>>` gives the compilation error `incompatible types: ArrayList<List<Number>> cannot be converted to List<List<? extends Number>>`. It's counter intuitive (to me), but you can't use List<List...>> on the LHS when `new ArrayList<List<...>>();` is on the RHS. Things get tricky with multi-level wildcards. See [What is the difference between <? extends Base> and <T extends Base>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60536437/2985643) for a recent related question.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not very familiar with Java syntax but it seems that your issue is this:

[Covariance & Contravariance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science))

Answer (score 3):

You should definitely use the ? type wildcard when appropriate, do not avoid it as a general rule. For example:

```
public void doThingWithList(List<List<? extends Number>> list);
```

allows you to pass a `List<Integer>` or a `List<Long>`.

```
public void doThingWithList(List<List<Number>> list);
```

allows you to only pass arguments declared as `List<Number>`. A small distinction, yes, but using the wildcard is powerful and **safe**. Contrary to how it may seem, a `List<Integer>` is not a subclass, or is not assignable, from `List<Number>`. Nor is `List<Integer>` a subclass of `List<? extends Number`, which is why the code above does not compile.

Answer (score 2):

Your statement does not compile because `List<? extends Number>` is not the same type as `List<Number>`. The former is a supertype of the latter.

Have you tried this? Here I'm expressing that the List is covariant in its type argument, so it will accept any subtype of `List<? extends Number>` (which includes `List<Number>`).

```
List<? extends List<? extends Number>> aList = new ArrayList<List<Number>>();
```

Or even this. Here the type parameter for the ArrayList on the right-hand side is the same as the type parameter on the left-hand side, so variance is not an issue.

```
List<List<? extends Number>> aList = new ArrayList<List<? extends Number>>();
```

You should be able to just say

```
List<List<Number>> aList = new ArrayList<List<Number>>();
```

I tend to avoid the `?` type wildcard whenever possible. I find that the expense incurred in type annotation is not worth the benefit.

Comment: These two suggestions will work, but it still doesn't explain the fact that the original statement doesn't work.

Answer (score -2):

```
List<List<? extends Number>> aList = new ArrayList<List<? extends Number>>();
aList.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
```