# multiple nested wildcard - arguments not applicable

Tags: java, generics, wildcard, compiler-errors

I've heavily simplified my problem. Here's how it reads.

I'm trying to figure out why the following code does not compile:

```
 List<AnonType<AnonType<?>>> l = new ArrayList<AnonType<AnonType<?>>>();
 l.add( new AnonType<AnonType<String>>() );
```

where

```
public class AnonType<T> {
  T a;

  List<T> b;
}
```

The compiler error is saying that add is not applicable for the argument given. OTOH, the following code with only 1-level nested wildcard compiles perfectly:

```
List<AnonType<?>> l = new ArrayList<AnonType<?>>();
l.add( new AnonType<String>() );
```

Comment: This has got to be a duplicate of half a dozen other questions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following compiles as expected:

```
    List<Set<? extends Set<?>>> list = new ArrayList<Set<? extends Set<?>>>();
    list.add(new HashSet<Set<String>>());
    list.add(new HashSet<Set<Integer>>());
```

The problem is that generics is type invariant.

Consider the simpler example:

- Given that there is a casting conversion from `Animal` to `Dog` (e.g. `Dog extends Animal`)...

  - A `List<Animal>` *IS NOT* a `List<Dog>`
- There is a capture conversion from `List<? extends Animal>` to a `List<Dog>`

Now here's what happens in this scenario:

- Given that there is a capture conversion from `Set<?>` to `Set<String>`...

  - A `Set<Set<?>>` *IS NOT* a `Set<Set<String>>`
- There is a capture conversion from `Set<? extends Set<?>>` to `Set<Set<String>>`

So if you want a `List<T>` where you can add a `Set<Set<String>>`, `Set<Set<Integer>>`, etc, then `T` is *NOT* `Set<Set<?>>`, but rather `Set<? extends Set<?>>`.

#### Related questions

- [Can't cast to to unspecific nested type with generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3575681/cant-cast-to-to-unspecific-nested-type-with-generics/)
- [Multiple wildcards on a generic methods makes Java compiler (and me!) very confused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546745/multiple-wildcards-on-a-generic-methods-makes-java-compiler-and-me-very-confus)
- [Java Generic `List<List<? extends Number>>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/746089/java-generic-listlist-extends-number)
- [Any simple way to explain why I cannot do `List<Animal> animals = new ArrayList<Dog>()`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2346763/any-simple-way-to-explain-why-i-cannot-do-listanimal-animals-new-arraylistdo)
- [What is the difference between `<E extends Number>` and `<Number>`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770264/what-is-the-difference-between-e-extends-number-and-number)

#### See also

- [Java Generics Tutorial](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/index.html)

  - [Generics and Subtyping](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/subtype.html) | [Wildcards](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html) | [More Fun with Wildcards](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/morefun.html)
- [Angelika Langer's Java Generics FAQ](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html)

  - [What is a bounded wildcard?](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TypeArguments.html#FAQ103)
  - [Which super-subtype relationships exist among instantiations of generic types?](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TechnicalDetails.html#FAQ207)

Comment: thank you, polygenelubricants. I was just reading your answer to the question you pointed as duplicate.

Comment: @andigenu: Yes, there's more explanation there and in a few other questions linked, but I thought I should still answer it here for a more direct answer to this question.

Comment: I appreciate it! I will also follow some of the links after I'm done with my current task, as I want to get a better grip of generics (which can be tricky).

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't compile because the type of the second argument in the `Pair<,>` of the statement is `String` and that type might not be the "unknown" type that was used in the declaration.  I think it will compile if you replace the `?` with `Object`.  Of course, you will then lose compile-time type-checking.