# Java generics incompatible types compilation error for generic static method call in Oracle Java SE 8u20 JDK

Tags: java, generics, compilation, type-erasure, incompatibletypeerror

When compiling the code below with the Oracle Java SE 8u20 JDK, the first three assignments compile fine (for the `works*` variables), but the fourth assignment (for the `fails1` variable) generates the following compilation error:

Error:

```
incompatible types: Set<Set<Object>> cannot be converted to Set<Set<? extends Object>>
```

Code:

```
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.Collections;

...

Set<? extends Object>      works1 = Collections.<Object>emptySet();
Set<Set<Object>>           works2 = Collections.<Set<Object>>emptySet();
Set<Set<? extends Object>> works3 = Collections.<Set<? extends Object>>emptySet();
Set<Set<? extends Object>> fails1 = Collections.<Set<Object>>emptySet();
```

I assume that this is correct (probably due to some sort of type erasure defined in the Java language specification), rather than being a bug, but I don't know for sure.

Does anyone know why `fails1` fails to compile?  A reference to the applicable part of the Java spec, or to a JDK bug report, would be appreciated.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: It doesn't compile on Java 7, either.

Comment: Remember that type erasure is never the answer to compilation errors such as your current one. At compile time there is no erasure---all type information is there.

Comment: I recommend reading this Q&A: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3652718/multiple-nested-wildcard-arguments-not-applicable

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: the answer from your link gave me the solution, which I'll answer below.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anything between `<` & `>` is type invariant unless you use a `?` wildcard.

The types of `Set<? extends Object>` & `Set<Object>` are different, and therefore need type variance to be considered compatible.

If they're at the top level, as for `works1`, the top-level `Set` is outside the `<` & `>`, so the normal Java type variance works, but for `fails1`, they're inside the `<` & `>`, so the types are invariant.

Type variance can be enabled within the `<` & `>` by changing the outermost part of the type declaration from `Set<Set<...>>` `Set<? extends Set<...>>`.

Thus, the following code compiles correctly:

```
Set<? extends Set<? extends Object>> works4 = Collections.<Set<Object>>emptySet();
```

I derived my answer from the answer to the following question (which was mentioned above by @MarkoTopolnik):

[multiple nested wildcard - arguments not applicable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3652718/multiple-nested-wildcard-arguments-not-applicable)

The answer to the following question provided a more detailed explanation:

[Can't cast to to unspecific nested type with generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3575681/cant-cast-to-to-unspecific-nested-type-with-generics)

Answer (score 2):

Your typing on `fails1` is being overly restrictive, which contradicts the relatively looser wildcard constraint being imposed on it at declaration.

An [upper-bounded wildcard](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/upperBounded.html) of the form `? extends T` implies that you are willing to accept `T` and all of its subtypes.  However, you explicitly restrict the right-hand side to `Object`.

In essence, you're trying to take:

```
Set<Set<? extends Object>>
```

which is a set of sets that contain something which is an `Object` or extends `Object`...

...and turn it into this:

```
Set<Object>
```

which is *only* a set of  `Object` types.

There's a reason why this situation doesn't happen with `works1`:  it defines a `Set` which contains elements of something that is an `Object` or a descendant of `Object`, and since `Object` fulfills at least one of those requirements, the [capture conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.10) being done in the background will fulfill this rule.

Then again, this is Java 8 you're working with - unless Java's compiler cannot do the type inference here, there is little gain in you passing in those types at all.

Comment: I think the most important message should be the difference between the `?` at the top level and the `?` in a nested position. I.e., why your explanation does not apply to `works1`. At face value, there is also a too-restrictive right-hand side there. And the difference is that a top-level `?` is subject to wildcard capture, whereas the nested one isn't.

Comment: That's not a bad idea.  I'll work that in in about a half-hour.  Going to try and formulate it in a way that's satisfactory to understand.