# How to assign an ArrayList<ArrayList<ClsA>> type object to List<List<ClsASuper>> variable in Java

Tags: java, types, containers

to program by contract or by interface, I define a class like this:

```
public ClsOne{
    private List<IntfA> fieldA;
    public setFieldA(List al);
}
public ClsA implements IntfA{...}
```

then in somewhere else, we can write:

```
....
ArrayList<ClsA> alist = new ArrayList<ClsA>();
ClsOne one = new ClsOne();
one.setFieldA(alist);
```

But, this seems not available for embedded containers:

```
public ClsTwo{
    private List<List<IntfA>> fieldA;
    public setFieldA(List<List<IntfA>> al);
}
public ClsA implements IntfA{...}
```

since the code below is not correct:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<ClsA>> aalist = new ArrayList<ArrayList<ClsA>>();
 ClsOne one = new ClsOne();
one.setFieldA(aalist);
```

So, is there any work around to hide concrete container type under this circumstance in ClsA's definition?

Comment: Compile error? runtime error? what is the error you are experiancing

Comment: I think you can fix it by saying something like List<? extends InfA>.  Try that.

Comment: Is there a reason  you need lists of lists? Maybe a different data structure would be more efficient. For example maybe a Map<KEY,List<IntfA>>

Comment: @RMT compile error. type doesn't fit.

Comment: @John Kane , I just want to keep a list of paths each has a list of nodes, to use Map, I have to generate another element for each path as a key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can instantiate an `ArrayList` which contains objects of type `List<ClsA>`:

```
ArrayList<List<ClsA>> aalist = new ArrayList<List<ClsA>>();
ClsOne one = new ClsOne();
one.setFieldA(aalist);
```

Comment: You should better make `aalist` a `List<List<ClsA>>`, to avoid problems like this.

Comment: @starblue absolutely, that's what i would do---but it's not strictly necessary to answer the question

Answer (score 1):

```
public setFieldA(List<? extends List<? extends IntfA>> al);
```

Should work. Java generics are sloppy and confusing and don't make a whole lot of sense.

Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/746089/java-generic-listlist-extends-number) if you want an explanation. I'd rather just use a better language.