# convert Collection<MyType> to Collection<Object>

Tags: java, generics

I have a class with the following constructor:

```
public UniqueField(Collection<Object> items) {
      this.items=items;
}
```

The idea behind the `Collection<Object>` is that I would be able to use `Collection<OtherType>`.

When doing:

```
Collection<OtherType> collection=... 
new UniqueField(collection);
```

I getting a compile error of invalid argument. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use this instead

```
public UniqueField(Collection<? extends Object> items) {
      this.items=items;
}
```

or ? because it is equal to "? extends Object"

```
public UniqueField(Collection<?> items) {
      this.items=items;
}
```

You can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/746089/java-generic-listlist-extends-number) for the reason

Answer (score 0):

you can use either:

```
public UniqueField(Collection<?> items) {
      this.items=items;
}
```

or:

```
public UniqueField(Collection<? super OtherType> items) {
      this.items=items;
}
```

or simply:

```
public UniqueField(Collection<OtherType> items) {
  this.items=items;
}
```